# Remove LAST number only from last of string in php

Tags: php, regex

I have images name like bellow.

```
mclaren-720s-exhaust-0.jpg
mclaren-720s-exhaust-1.jpg
mclaren-720s-exhaust-02.jpg
mclaren-720s-exhaust-03.jpg
```

Now I want to convert image name into string to use text on ALT/TITLE for image tag.
I want to remove last number only like  0/1/02/03 from image name not 720.

so from  mclaren-720s-exhaust-03.jpg TO  mclaren 720s exhaust.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Are these images in different folders? Be careful with equal file names.

Comment: @ÉderRochaBezerra  Yes have different folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this `remove_last_number()` function:

```
function remove_last_number($file_string) {

    //remove extension from string
    $filename = substr($file_string, 0 , (strrpos($file_string, ".")));

    //break the filename by the `-` character, creating an array of each section
    $filename_parts = explode('-', $filename);

    //remove the last part of the filename, add it back if it contains any digits that aren't numbers
    $last_elem = array_pop($filename_parts);
    if (!preg_match("/^\d+$/", $last_elem)) {
        $filename_parts[] = $last_elem;
    }     

    //return correct filename by imploding all the parts back together and adding the extension.
    return implode(' ', $filename_parts);

}
```

Usage:

```
echo remove_last_number('mclaren-720s-exhaust-0.jpg');
echo remove_last_number('mclaren-720s-exhaust-1.jpg');
echo remove_last_number('mclaren-720s-exhaust-02.jpg');
echo remove_last_number('mclaren-720s-exhaust-03.jpg');
echo remove_last_number('mclaren-720s-exhaust-03d.jpg');
```

Results:

```
mclaren 720s exhaust
mclaren 720s exhaust
mclaren 720s exhaust
mclaren 720s exhaust
mclaren 720s exhaust 03d
```

Comment: Got it. I can add additional condition to check if $filename_parts  last element have number in value.  thanks

Comment: @YogeshSaroya Check my update, I added that condition check. If the last element contains anything other than numbers, it's re-added to the returned string. Or should it remove if it contains _any_ numbers?

Comment: Remove only if Number if have number with char then no.  "mclaren 720s exhaust 03d
" is correct. thanks

Comment: @YogeshSaroya Perfect. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add next regex:

```php
function removeLastNumber(string $imageName): string
{
    return str_replace(
        '-', 
        ' ', 
        preg_replace(
            '~^((.+)(?:\-[0-9]+)|(.+\-([a-z]+\d+|\d+[a-z]+)))\.\w{3,4}$~', 
            '$2$3', 
            $imageName
        )
    );
}

echo removeLastNumber('mclaren-720s-exhaust-02.jpg'); //mclaren 720s exhaust
echo removeLastNumber('mclaren-720s-exhaust-02d.jpg'); //mclaren 720s exhaust 02d
```

It will work as with 'mclaren-720s-exhaust-02.jpg' as with 'mclaren-720s-exhaust-02d.jpg' as well.